# Should one consider Phenomenology as a turn from Aristotle's eternal substances to Heraclitean flux?

Tags: continental-philosophy, phenomenology, heidegger

Both Plato & Aristotle had a philosophy of *stasis*. That is Plato's theory of forms which appear to be outside of time. Whereas Aristotle's theory of *substance* is actually in time but stripped of *accidents*.

Of course, the Western philosophical tradition is dominated by Christian theology (even in recent secular times where it remains *the* significant rival) - and here God is eternal.

Furthermore, the key principles of physical science are the laws of conservation. That is: what remains invariant.

Now, in contrast to this - Heraclitus, a pre-Socratic philosopher focused on *flux* of *phenomena* as marked in his famous aphorism:

> You can't step in the same river twice.

Heidegger, a founder of Phenomenology devoted a seminar in the 1960s to Heraclitus. This appears to be good evidence for this point of view. Furthermore, he also devoted another seminar to Holderlin's poem *Der Ister* (*The River*); and Holderlin was acquainted with Heraclitus:

> Yet the river almost seems
>
> To flow backwards, and I
>
> Think it must come
>
> From the East

Heraclitus, was a native of the Greek city Ephesus, Ionia, on the coast of Asia Minor. That is the East.

Comment: Check out Nietzsche as well. He specifically supports Heraclitus' views and rejects any "absolute, changeless" ideas (like Plato's and Aristotle's), which is also part of the reason why he rejects the Judea-Christian tradition (but not the main one).

Comment: @ChaosAndOrder: where does he say that?

Comment: It follows from the "death of God". A good example is “I shall reiterate a hundred times that ‘immediate certainty’, like ‘absolute knowledge’ and ‘thing in itself,’ contains a contradictio in adjecto [contradiction in terms]: we really ought to get free from the seduction of words!” (Beyond Good and Evil I.16)

Comment: ok, but where does he specifically mention Heraclitus?

Comment: I think "Philosophy in the tragic age of the Greeks" is where he speaks about Heraclitus (and other Greek philosophers).

Answer (score 2):

No. That would just be swapping one metaphysics for another, while Heidegger, in *Sein und Zeit* at least, is concerned with unquestioned, precursory relation between being and time. E.g. the fact you already divide time in statis (eternal) versus flux (temporary).